# Is there a way to create an alias of reviewers that can be added to a github pull request all at once?

Tags: github

The way we do pull requests at my company, we require 5 specific people to be on all pull requests into Repository A, and a different list of 4 people on all pull requests into Repository B. It's kinda a pain to remember which names go where and not leave anyone out.

**Is there a way I can create an alias or something that will autofill in the review request fields that will add all the appropriate people?**

For instance, I want to create RepositoryAReviewers and RepositoryBReviewers, and then whenever I pull request to either repository I can just put the alias in the review request field and hit submit. Does this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is create teams for these groups.  For example, when I wish to merge code at work, I use the `my-company/my-team-reviewers` team, which pings all of the reviewers on my team.  `my-company` is the name of your GitHub organization.

If you additionally want to require all reviews for a certain repository (or certain files within that repository) to be from a certain team, you can use the [`CODEOWNERS` file](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners) to do so.  That's especially useful if you have a core team for a project that you always want to do reviews, or if teams are responsible for certain subsystems.

A `CODEOWNERS` file that affects the entire repository would look like this:

```
* @my-company/core-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem last week and made a simple chrome extension to create/save lists of usernames and bulk-add these lists as reviewers on my currently open PR

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-reviewer-groups/mmgjipidkhkfimmfgcgklooinlcfonah?hl=en&authuser=0

It's open source too, so feel free to try improving it. The repo is here: https://github.com/KhaledAylii/Github-Reviewer-Groups/tree/master